# Windows - CD to the most likely folder

Tags: windows, cd

Is there a possible way to run `cd` (i.e navigate) to a given folder without mentioning its full name?

For instance, given the following structure:

```
- lorem
  - ipsum
  - delor
```

Is there any option to do something like `...\lorem>cd ^del` that would be equal by doing `...\lorem>cd delor`?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do that kind of thing.  The directory listing can be sorted and displayed in different ways, so this type of shorthand would be very unreliable.

Comment: As with Linux, you can press <tab> to auto complete the file/folder name. `del<tab>`

Comment: @Appleoddity Thanks! Haven't thought of trying to press tab. It works on Windows and MacOS too